# Avoiding GeoServer/Java out of heap space error?

Tags: geoserver, java, performance

I'm new to Geoserver, Ubuntu and Java, but have downloaded a virtual machine from gisvm.com and am getting up to speed. I got as far as configuring it with some fairly large shapefiles from a project I've worked on previously.

My question is related to a problem which I see if I show the shapefile using the OpenLayers layer preview option. I see an error:

> OpenLayers map preview code="internalError" Rendering process failed.
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Googling has led me to plenty of Java command line options to increase heap space, but I have no idea if this should be applied to an environment variable, in a startup script or as a part of the Geoserver config.

Can you help me to understand what I need to edit to get this working?

I'm also wondering if I should be splitting my shapefile into smaller pieces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must change memory heap in your JVM.
I supposed that gisvm.com use Tomcat, so you can find a lot of tutorials about "increase java heap space in Tomcat" in google.
Basically is add -Xmx128m parameter to JVM to increasing memory heap.

Comment: Ah, ok, I found that /etc/default/tomcat6 contains this line:
JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx128m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC" - I guess I edit that? Trying  -Xmx512m ...

Comment: I tried it and it worked! Thanks for the pointer to Tomcat, I hadn't realised that it was involved.

Answer (score 6):

I've had the same error message on a **Windows Server** with GeoServer using **Jetty**. After some research I found the file `C:\Program Files (x86)\GeoServer 2.10.1\wrapper\wrapper.conf` where I edited these two lines:

```
# Initial Java Heap Size (in MB)
wrapper.java.initmemory=16

# Maximum Java Heap Size (in MB)
wrapper.java.maxmemory=128
```

Seems to have done the trick...

I found a hint to this file here: http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Geoserver-heap-size-permgen-space-configuration-td5145590.html

Answer (score 3):

You can increase Memory Allocation in the following ways

(performance settings in the Java virtual machine (JVM) for your container)

**-Xmx256M -Xms48m**

> "Allocates extra memory to your server. By default, JVM
>   will use only 64MB of heap. If you’re
>   serving just vector data, you’ll be
>   streaming, so having more memory won’t
>   increase performance. If you’re
>   serving coverages, however, JAI will
>   use a disk cache. -Xmx256M allocates
>   256MB of memory to GeoServer (use more
>   if you have excess memory). It is also
>   a good idea to configure the JAI tile
>   cache size (see the Server Config page
>   in the Web Administration Interface
>   section) so that it uses 75% of the
>   heap (0.75). -Xmx48m will tell the
>   virtual machine to grab a 48MB heap on
>   startup, which will make heap
>   management more stable during heavy
>   load serving."

**-XX:MaxPermSize=128m**

> "Increases the maximum size of
>   permanent generation (or “permgen”)
>   allocated to GeoServer to 128MB.
>   Permgen is the heap portion where the
>   class bytecode is stored. GeoServer
>   uses lots of classes, and it may
>   exhaust that space quickly, leading to
>   out of memory errors. This is
>   especially important if you’re
>   deploying GeoServer along with other
>   applications in the same container, or
>   if you need to deploy multiple
>   GeoServer instances inside the same
>   container."

http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/production/container.html

Comment: Thanks; I found this previously but it didn't help me much. From my unfamiliar-with-this-stuff point of view, it doesn't tell me what to edit in my Ubuntu VM - where do I put those switches? Where do I find the 'performance settings in the Java virtual machine (JVM) for your container'?

Comment: Well, to my understanding the options you mentioned are valid for Oracle's JVM, that is, not standard, and even not stable. "Options that begin with -X are non-standard (not guaranteed to be supported on all VM implementations), and are subject to change without notice in subsequent releases of the JDK. Options that are specified with -XX are not stable and are not recommended for casual use. These options are subject to change without notice." (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html). The question has problem: Elliveny is not telling us what JVM is using.

Comment: Java is owned by oracle - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29 So GeoServer should be bundling extensions with the package. I found all the extensions for oracle connections disjointed but did get it to work.

Comment: @Mapperz Java is not owned by Oracle. There are a lot of implementations of JVM. but the more famous implementation is Oracle JVM. List  (not complete) of JVM implementations: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_virtual_machines

Answer (score 3):

Changing Java Heap Memory for Geoserver

> sudo vi /usr/share/tomcat7/bin/catalina.sh

line 3

> export CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms2048m -Xmx8g"

Change the `"-Xmx2048m"` to desired value, as `Xmx` is case sensitive, you can use `"g"` for GB or `"m"` for MB

After the changes are saved, remember to restart `tomcat`:

> sudo services tomcat7 restart

Comment: The command for restart is "sudo service tomcat7 restart"

Comment: It is not recommended to change the catalina.sh, instead add "setenv.sh" described here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398053/cant-change-tomcat-7-heap-size/10950387#10950387