# Problem while adding the store/layer in geoserver

Tags: geoserver

I am new to geoserver..Yesterday I worked with that and added stores and layers. Its working fine.
But, Today I try to add a new store, i am getting this error message..

***"Sorry, your session timed out...
It looks like you waited too long to make that last change.if this continues to happen, you should get in touch with your system administrator.
Go back to the home page and try again."***

How to resolve this error..
Could u please help me out..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [mail list](http://en.it-usenet.org/thread/12186/15331/), "you are likely running out of permgen space". To increase it, follow [Geoserver/java out of heap space - how do I increase it?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10428/geoserver-java-out-of-heap-space-how-do-i-increase-it/10435#10435)

Comment: Problem has been resolved..
Than Q.. :-)