# GeoServer Timeout and restart while accessing WMS layer images

Tags: geoserver, wms

We are having GeoServer setup with a PostGIS database. The issue I am facing is that it times out often when trying to access a layer which is built with large data.

I have tried:
Enabled GeowebCache, direct integration with WMS service , but it does not help and it still crashes, so even if I do seeding, the data gets wiped off after it restarts.
Tried to update few rendering params such as max rendering memory but the issue still persist.
Updated jvm heap config.

In the GeoServer log I can see one exception but it comes randomly so not sure if that is causing anything.
Adding error trace also.

```
 BgColor = java.awt.Color[r=255,g=255,b=255]
Buffer = 0
Clip = null
CQLFilter = [[[ hoco_num = 130317 ]]]
Crs = PROJCS["WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator", 
GEOGCS["WGS 84", 
DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984", 
SPHEROID["WGS 84", 6378137.0, 298.257223563, AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]], 
AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]], 
PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0, AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]], 
UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], 
AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH], 
AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST], 
AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]], 
PROJECTION["Popular Visualisation Pseudo Mercator", AUTHORITY["EPSG","1024"]], 
PARAMETER["semi_minor", 6378137.0], 
PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin", 0.0], 
PARAMETER["central_meridian", 0.0], 
PARAMETER["scale_factor", 1.0], 
PARAMETER["false_easting", 0.0], 
PARAMETER["false_northing", 0.0], 
UNIT["m", 1.0], 
AXIS["Easting", EAST], 
AXIS["Northing", NORTH], 
AUTHORITY["EPSG","3857"]]
Elevation = []
Env = {}
Exceptions = SE_XML
FeatureId = null
FeatureVersion = null
Filter = [[[ hoco_num = 130317 ]]]
Format = image/png
FormatOptions = {}
Get = true
Height = 598
Interpolations = []
Layers = [org.geoserver.wms.MapLayerInfo@15518bbe]
MaxFeatures = null
Palette = null
RawKvp = {REQUEST=GetMap, CRS=EPSG:3857, FORMAT=image/png, BBOX=-9547272.565037575,3909103.9755447335,-9221956.57265602,4091941.3472027867, VERSION=1.3.0, STYLES=green, SERVICE=WMS, WIDTH=1064, HEIGHT=598, CQL_FILTER=test_val IN (fdsf), TRANSPARENT=true, LAYERS=test_layer}
RemoteOwsType = null
RemoteOwsURL = null
Request = GetMap
RequestCharset = UTF-8
ScaleMethod = null
Sld = null
SldBody = null
SldVersion = null
SortBy = null
SortByArrays = null
SRS = urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG:3857
StartIndex = null
StyleBody = null
StyleFormat = sld
Styles = [StyleImpl[ name=green]]
StyleUrl = null
StyleVersion = null
Tiled = false
TilesOrigin = null
Time = []
Transparent = true
ValidateSchema = false
Version = 1.3.0
ViewParams = null
Width = 1064
16 Jun 08:52:17 DEBUG [wms.map] - Writing png image ...
16 Jun 08:52:17 DEBUG [geoserver.filters] - Not compressing output for mimetype: image/png
16 Jun 08:52:17 DEBUG [wms.map] - Writing png image ... done!
16 Jun 08:52:17 DEBUG [filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1] - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
16 Jun 08:56:12 DEBUG [geoserver.security] - AuthenticationCache Eviction task running
16 Jun 08:56:12 DEBUG [geoserver.security] - Cache entries #: 0
16 Jun 08:56:12 DEBUG [geoserver.security] - AuthenticationCache Eviction task completed
16 Jun 08:56:12 DEBUG [geoserver.security] - Cache entries #: 0
16 Jun 08:56:13 DEBUG [security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /web, QueryString: null'; against '/web/**'
16 Jun 08:56:13 DEBUG [security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Matched Path: /web, QueryString: null with /web/**
16 Jun 08:56:13 DEBUG [geoserver.filters] - Creating a new http session inside the web UI (normal behavior)
java.lang.Exception: Full stack trace for the session creation path
at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter$SessionDebugWrapper.getSession(SessionDebugFilter.java:92)
at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter$SessionDebugWrapper.getSession(SessionDebugFilter.java:66)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:279)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:47)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:142)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:101)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:77)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:47)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:46)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.handle(CrossOriginFilter.java:311)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.doFilter(CrossOriginFilter.java:265)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1602)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1700)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1667)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:220)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:152)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:505)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:370)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:267)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:698)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:804)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
16 Jun 08:56:13 DEBUG [security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /web, QueryString: null'; against '/web/**'
16 Jun 08:56:13 DEBUG [security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Matched Path: /web, QueryString: null with /web/**
16 Jun 08:56:13 DEBUG [geoserver.filters] - Creating a new http session inside the web UI (normal behavior)
java.lang.Exception: Full stack trace for the session creation path
at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter$SessionDebugWrapper.getSession(SessionDebugFilter.java:92)
at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter$SessionDebugWrapper.getSession(SessionDebugFilter.java:66)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:279)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:47)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:142)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:101)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:77)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:47)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:46)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.handle(CrossOriginFilter.java:311)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.doFilter(CrossOriginFilter.java:265)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1602)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1700)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1667)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:220)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:152)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:505)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:370)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:267)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:698)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:804)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
16 Jun 08:56:13 DEBUG [filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1] - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
16 Jun 08:56:13 DEBUG [filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1] - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
16 Jun 08:56:13 DEBUG [security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Checking match of request : 'Path: /web, QueryString: null'; against '/web/**'
16 Jun 08:56:13 DEBUG [security.IncludeQueryStringAntPathRequestMatcher] - Matched Path: /web, QueryString: null with /web/**
16 Jun 08:56:13 DEBUG [geoserver.filters] - Creating a new http session inside the web UI (normal behavior)
java.lang.Exception: Full stack trace for the session creation path
at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter$SessionDebugWrapper.getSession(SessionDebugFilter.java:92)
at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter$SessionDebugWrapper.getSession(SessionDebugFilter.java:66)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getSession(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:279)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:47)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:74)
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:91)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178)
at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:142)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:101)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
at org.geoserver.filters.XFrameOptionsFilter.doFilter(XFrameOptionsFilter.java:77)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:47)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:46)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:42)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.handle(CrossOriginFilter.java:311)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter.doFilter(CrossOriginFilter.java:265)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1602)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:146)
at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:548)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:257)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1700)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1667)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:220)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:152)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:505)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:370)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:267)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:117)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:698)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:804)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
16 Jun 08:56:13 DEBUG [filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1] - SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
2021-06-16 09:01:01.133:INFO:oejs.AbstractConnector:Thread-0: Stopped ServerConnector@76a117db{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8080}
2021-06-16 09:01:01.137:INFO:oejs.session:Thread-0: node0 Stopped scavenging
2021-06-16 09:01:01.138:INFO:oejshC.geoserver:Thread-0: Destroying Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
2021-06-16 09:01:01.144:INFO:oejshC.geoserver:Thread-0: Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
16 Jun 09:01:01 INFO [georss.GeoRSSPoller] - destroy() invoked
16 Jun 09:01:01 INFO [geowebcache.GeoWebCacheDispatcher] - GeoWebCacheDispatcher.destroy() was invoked, shutting down.
16 Jun 09:01:01 INFO [diskquota.DiskQuotaMonitor] - Disk quota monitor shutting down...
16 Jun 09:01:01 INFO [diskquota.DiskQuotaMonitor] - Shutting down quota usage monitor...
16 Jun 09:01:01 INFO [diskquota.QuotaUpdatesMonitor] - Shutting down quota usage monitor...
16 Jun 09:01:01 INFO [diskquota.QueuedQuotaUpdatesConsumer] - Shutting down quota update background task due to InterruptedException
16 Jun 09:01:01 INFO [diskquota.DiskQuotaMonitor] - Shutting down quota statistics gathering monitor...
16 Jun 09:01:01 INFO [diskquota.QueuedUsageStatsConsumer] - Shutting down quota update background task due to interrupted exception
16 Jun 09:01:01 INFO [jdbc.JDBCQuotaStore] - Closing up the JDBC quota store 
16 Jun 09:01:01 INFO [seed.SeederThreadPoolExecutor] - Initiating shut down for running and pending seed tasks...
16 Jun 09:01:01 INFO [seed.SeederThreadPoolExecutor] - Seeder thread pool executor shut down complete.
16 Jun 09:01:01 INFO [storage.DefaultStorageBroker] - Destroying StorageBroker
16 Jun 09:01:01 WARN [support.DisposableBeanAdapter] - Destroy method 'destroy' on bean with name 'gwcMemoryBlobStore' threw an exception: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@2513432a rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@48d7a964[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 1]
16 Jun 09:01:01 WARN [support.DisposableBeanAdapter] - Invocation of destroy method failed on bean with name 'geoServerLoader': org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'geoWebCacheExtensions': Singleton bean creation not allowed while singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
2021-06-16 09:01:02.267:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:Thread-0: Stopped o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@5ec0a365{GeoServer,/geoserver,null,UNAVAILABLE}{/geoserver}
```

Comment: 1) That is not the relevant part of the log - you're looking for `caused by` - 2) your data and cache should not be "wiped out" by a crash 3) don't use Jetty for production services 4) what did you set the JVM startup params to? Please use the [edit] link to add more details of what is actually happening

Comment: Thanks for checking this @IanTurton . I have updated the more relevant log I found from Geoserver.  We have updated the jvm params as per the suggestion on this post https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10428/avoiding-geoserver-java-out-of-heap-space-error