# OpenLayers map preview code="internalError" Rendering process failed. java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: geoserver, java

I am using geoserver 2.14.4 (Operating system independent runnable binary). Last couple of days, my server is gradually slow down. and after 2/3 days it will stop showing anything by showing below error msg:
**OpenLayers map preview code="internalError" Rendering process failed. java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space**
My server is Ubuntu 18.4 i found here a solution here [Avoiding GeoServer/Java out of heap space error?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/10428/avoiding-geoserver-java-out-of-heap-space-error)
but is it for Windows OS. Here is a .config file in *C:\Program Files (x86)\GeoServer 2.10.1\wrapper\wrapper.conf* What is for ubuntu OS? or for Operating system independent runnable binary??

Comment: did you look at this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/136279/79)?

Comment: yes, but i am not using tomcat, i am using planform independent binary pagkage